# How to get key name by it's value as they are list in python file?

Tags: python, import

I have a python file named "parameters.py" within this:

```
good = '100'
bad = '110'
ok = '120'
```

I want to import this file, and to find the key name by it's value.

something like:

```
import parameters
for k, v in parameters.iteritems():
    if v == '110':
        print str(k)
```

this not really works (method has no member iteritems...)

thanks for helpers!

Comment: Why not just group the values into a dictionary?

Comment: this file using by lots of views, can't re-factor this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through `dir(parameters)` to get the keys, or `vars(parameters).iteritems()`. You will have to skip some members though:

```
>>> dir(settings)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'bad', 'good', 'ok']
```

For practical use, I'd recommend wrapping `good`, `bad` and `ok` in a `dict` stored in the `parameters` module:

```
# parameters.py

HAM = {  # or whatever this represents
    good: '100',
    bad: '110',
    ok: '120',
}
```

Comment: thanks. what the diff between dir to vars? vars return list and dir return dict?

Comment: @eligro: the other way around, actually.

Answer (score 3):

`vars(parameters)` will get you a dictionary with key-value pairs for all the top-level definitions in the module. As larsmans notes, you'll have to skip some, as it will include `__doc__` and other special variables.

Comment: +1 for `vars`; I replaced my advice to use `__dict__` directly.